# Datetime-local set default hours

Tags: javascript, datetime, datetimepicker

I'm using the following input :

```
<input id="creation-from-date" type="datetime-local"/>
```

I'd like know if there is a way to set default hours like this :
**dd/mm/yyyy 00:00**

Because the datepicker allows to pick date only, not time so I get an invalid date in JS side because the hours is not set.

I'm using Chrome v73.0.3683.75

Many thanks !

Comment: Can you please add (to the question itself) how you initialize your datepicker?

Comment: I don't, datetime-local is a Bootstrap's component as far as I know. I'm retrieve the value via jQuery `$("#creation-from-date").val();`

Comment: Yes I saw this plugin but I also need to set time, and this plugin is only for date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `<input type='date' />` and `<input type='time' />` instead:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* external.js */
var doc, bod, I, DateTime; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', function(){
doc = document; bod = doc.body;
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
DateTime = function(dateElement, timeElement, dateInstance){
  var t = this;
  this.dateElement = dateElement; this.timeElement = timeElement;
  this.date = dateInstance instanceof Date ? dateInstance : new Date;

  this.dateValue = function(dateInstance){
    if(dateInstance instanceof Date)this.date = dateInstance;
    var dt = this.date;
    return dt.getFullYear()+'-'+(dt.getMonth()+1).toString().replace(/^(\d)$/, '0$1')+'-'+dt.getDate().toString().replace(/^(\d)$/, '0$1');
  }
  this.showDate = function(dateInstance){
    this.dateElement.value = this.dateValue(dateInstance);
    return this;
  }
  this.timeValue = function(dateInstance){
    if(dateInstance instanceof Date)this.date = dateInstance;
    var dt = this.date;
    return dt.getHours().toString().replace(/^(\d)$/, '0$1')+':'+dt.getMinutes().toString().replace(/^(\d)$/, '0$1');
  }
  this.showTime = function(dateInstance){
    this.timeElement.value = this.timeValue(dateInstance);
    return this;
  }
  this.showDate().showTime();
  this.dateChange = function(changeFunc, noTimeFunc){
    this.dateElement.oninput = function(){
      var v = this.value, s = t.timeElement.value;
      if(v === '')v = this.value = t.dateValue(noTimeFunc(t));
      if(s === '')s = t.timeValue(this.date);
      t.date = new Date(v+' '+s); changeFunc(t.date, t);
    }
    return this;
  }
  this.timeChange = function(changeFunc, noTimeFunc){
    this.timeElement.oninput = function(){
      var v = this.value, s = t.dateElement.value;
      if(v === '')v = this.value = t.timeValue(noTimeFunc(t));
      if(s === '')s = t.dateValue(this.date);
      t.date = new Date(s+' '+v); changeFunc(t.date, t);
    }
    return this;
  }
}
var dateElement = I('date'), timeElement = I('time');
function threeHoursLater(){
  return new Date(Date.now()+10800000);
}
var dt = new DateTime(dateElement, timeElement, threeHoursLater()); //  3 hours from now - initial date time set
function consoleIt(dateInstance){
  console.log('display of dt.date --> '+dateInstance.toString());
  console.log('dt.date for server --> '+dateInstance.getTime());
}
consoleIt(dt.date);
dt.dateChange(function(r){
  consoleIt(r);
}, threeHoursLater).timeChange(function(a){
  consoleIt(a);
}, threeHoursLater);
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```html
<input id='date' type='date' />
<input id='time' type='time' />
```

Close those inputs and see what happens! Oh, make sure you validate those dates on your Server. The Client can be altered.

I have update the above code to include a `DateTime` constructor. The arguments should be clear.

PS

I noticed that there is an issue in Firefox 67.0 (64-bit) with change events, on Elements that do not receive focus first, therefore `.onchange` was changed to `.oninput`, which seems to work across the board.

Comment: Thank you ! I'm gonna use this. But is there a way to set only the hours ? I do not want the date to be initialized at today's date.

Comment: I've made an edit to show you how to set hours in the future.

Comment: Clean ! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Try to add default date for it

```
document.getElementById("creation-from-date").value = setDefautValue();
    function setDefautValue() {
        var date = new Date(); // today
        date.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0); //set default time 00:00 AM
        const dStr = date.toISOString()
        // remove seconds and milliseconds
        return dStr.substring(0, dStr.indexOf(':', dStr.indexOf(':')+1))
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but your code is based on today's date. This is not suitable with my use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Javascripts date:

```
$("creation-from-date").val(new Date().toLocalString());
// toLocalString() will return the local time while toISOString() will return the UTC time.
```

Here a good [jQuery extension](https://gist.github.com/ryanburnette/8803238) that is pretty useful for initializing `datetime` and `datetime-local` inputs:

```
// To initialize, simply call the method:
$('input[type="datetime-local"]').setNow();
```

Hope this helps.